# Lower Bound of Sum of Squares of Cosines in a Triangle Using Vectors

Tags: trigonometry, vector-analysis

Is there a vector algebra/calculus proof of the fact that $\cos^{2} A + \cos^{2} B + \cos^{2} C \geq \frac{3}{4}$ for *any* triangle $\Delta ABC$? I have seen many algebra/trig proofs, but I was wondering if there was a way to prove this using vectors, like the way you prove the law of cosines from expanding $(\vec{u} - \vec{v})^{2}$?

This is my progress so far:

A triangle can be specified by two vectors, $\vec{u}$ and $\vec{v}$; these form two sides of a triangle (the vertex being at the origin). Then, $\vec{v} - \vec{u}$ forms the other side. Let $u = |\vec{u}|$ and $v = |\vec{v}|$, and $(\vec{v} - \vec{u})^{2} = (\vec{v} - \vec{u}) \cdot (\vec{v} - \vec{u}) = u^{2} + v^{2} - 2 \vec{u} \cdot \vec{v}$. If $A$ denotes the angle between $\vec{u}$ and $\vec{v}$ at the origin, then $\cos^{2} A = \frac{(\vec{u} \cdot \vec{v})^{2}}{u^{2} v^{2}}$. Likewise, if $B$ denotes the angle between $\vec{u}$ and $\vec{v} - \vec{u}$, then $\cos^{2} B = \frac{((\vec{v} - \vec{u}) \cdot u)^{2}}{(\vec{v} - \vec{u})^{2}u^{2}} = \frac{(\vec{v} \cdot \vec{u} - u^{2})^{2}}{(\vec{v} - \vec{u})^{2} u^{2}} = \frac{(\vec{v} \cdot \vec{u})^{2} - 2u^{2}(\vec{v}\cdot \vec{u})+u^{4}}{(\vec{v} - \vec{u})^{2}u^{2}}$. If $C$ denotes the angle between $\vec{v} - \vec{u}$ and $\vec{v}$, then $\cos^{2} C = \frac{((\vec{v} - \vec{u}) \cdot v)^{2}}{(\vec{v} - \vec{u})^{2}v^{2}} = \frac{(\vec{v} \cdot \vec{u} - v^{2})^{2}}{(\vec{v} - \vec{u})^{2} v^{2}} = \frac{(\vec{v} \cdot \vec{u})^{2} - 2v^{2}(\vec{v}\cdot \vec{u})+v^{4}}{(\vec{v} - \vec{u})^{2}v^{2}}$. Using the common denominator of $(\vec{v} - \vec{u})^{2}u^{2}v^{2}$, we then have the following:
$$\cos^{2}A + \cos^{2} B + \cos^{2} C = \frac{(\vec{u} \cdot \vec{v})^{2}[(\vec{v} - \vec{u})^{2}+u^{2} + v^{2}] - 4(\vec{u} \cdot \vec{v})u^{2}v^{2} +u^{4}v^{2} + u^{2}v^{4}}{(\vec{v} - \vec{u})^{2}u^{2}v^{2}}$$
Simplifying the numerator gives:
$$\cos^{2} A + \cos^{2} B + \cos^{2} C = \frac{u^{2}v^{2}(u^{2} + v^{2} - 4(\vec{u} \cdot \vec{v})) + 2(\vec{u} \cdot \vec{v})^{2}(u^{2} + v^{2} - \vec{u} \cdot \vec{v}) }{(\vec{v} - \vec{u})^{2}u^{2}v^{2}}$$

The statement that $\cos^{2} A + \cos^{2} B + \cos^{2} C \geq \frac{3}{4}$ then becomes equivalent to the statement that
$$u^{2}v^{2}(u^{2}+v^{2} - 4(\vec{u} \cdot \vec{v})) + 2(\vec{u} \cdot \vec{v})(u^{2} + v^{2} - \vec{u} \cdot \vec{v}) \geq \frac{3}{4} (u^{2} + v^{2} - 2 \vec{u} \cdot \vec{v})u^{2}v^{2}$$
Subtracting the right-hand side from the left-hand side gives:
$$\frac{1}{4}u^{2}v^{2}(u^{2} + v^{2} - 10(\vec{u} \cdot \vec{v})) + 2(\vec{u} \cdot \vec{v})(u^{2} + v^{2} - \vec{u} \cdot \vec{v}) \geq 0$$
One thought I had to prove this inequality was to rewrite the left-hand side as follows:

$$\frac{1}{4}v^{2}(u^{2} - 2(\vec{u} \cdot \vec{v}))^{2} + \frac{1}{4}u^{2}(v^{2} - 2(\vec{u} \cdot \vec{v}))^{2} + (\vec{u} \cdot \vec{v})^{2} - \frac{1}{2}(\vec{u} \cdot \vec{v})u^{2}v^{2} - (\vec{u} \cdot \vec{v})^{3}$$

It would then suffice to show that $ (\vec{u} \cdot \vec{v})^{2} - \frac{1}{2}(\vec{u} \cdot \vec{v})u^{2}v^{2} - (\vec{u} \cdot \vec{v})^{3} \geq 0$ or equivalently that
$(\vec{u} \cdot \vec{v}) ((\vec{u} \cdot \vec{v})-\frac{1}{2}u^{2}v^{2} -(\vec{u} \cdot \vec{v})^{2}) \geq 0$. However, if $\vec{u} \cdot \vec{v} = \frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}$ and $u^{2} = v^{2} = 1$ (angle $A$ is $30^{\circ}$), then $(\vec{u} \cdot \vec{v})(\vec{u} \cdot \vec{v} - \frac{1}{2}u^{2}v^{2}-(\vec{u} \cdot \vec{v})) = \frac{1}{8}(6- 5\sqrt{3}) < 0$.

Is there another way to rewrite $$\frac{1}{4}u^{2}v^{2}(u^{2} + v^{2} - 10(\vec{u} \cdot \vec{v})) + 2(\vec{u} \cdot \vec{v})(u^{2} + v^{2} - \vec{u} \cdot \vec{v})$$ as a linear combination of
$(u^{2} - 2\vec{u} \cdot \vec{v})^{2}$ and $(v^{2} - 2\vec{u} \cdot \vec{v})^{2}$ (with coefficients that are all nonnegative?) Note that the equality case should imply that $A = B = C = 60^{\circ}$, which should be equivalent, in this context, to $u^{2} = 2 \vec{u} \cdot \vec{v}$ and $v^{2} = 2\vec{u} \cdot \vec{v}$.

$A = 60^{\circ} \iff u^{2}v^{2}=4(u \cdot v)^{2}$;

$B = 60^{\circ} \iff (\vec{u} - \vec{v})^{2}u^{2} = 4(\vec{u} \cdot (\vec{v} - \vec{u}))^{2} \iff u^{4} + u^{2}v^{2} - 2(\vec{u} \cdot \vec{v})u^{2} = 4u^{4} + 4(\vec{u} \cdot \vec{v})^{2}- 8(\vec{u} \cdot \vec{v})u^{2} \iff 3u^{4}  - 6(\vec{u} \cdot \vec{v})u^{2}  = 0 \iff u^{2} = 2 u \cdot v$$

$C= 60^{\circ} \iff (\vec{u} - \vec{v})^{2}v^{2} = 4(\vec{u} \cdot (\vec{v} - \vec{u}))^{2} \iff v^{4} + u^{2}v^{2} - 2(\vec{u} \cdot \vec{v})v^{2} = 4v^{4} + 4(\vec{u} \cdot \vec{v})^{2}- 8(\vec{u} \cdot \vec{v})v^{2} \iff 3v^{4}  - 6(\vec{u} \cdot \vec{v})v^{2}  = 0 \iff v^{2} = 2 \vec{u} \cdot \vec{v}$ )

Comment: I think there is an error in your calculation. Think of units of length for each vector, and the units of each term must match. In some expressions you add length to the 6th with length to the fourth power.

Comment: Alternate way: let $f(x,y)=\cos^2x+\cos^2y+\cos^2(x+y)$ with $x>0,y>0,x+y<\pi$ (and $x\le \pi/2$ WLOG), and find its minimum using calculus. You should find that you must have $x=y$, then $\cos(x)=\frac12$, and the minimum of $f$ is obtained with an equilateral triangle.

Comment: This is a repost of [a question you posted a few weeks ago](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4696571/409). Reposting a question is not the appropriate way to attract more attention to it (or to deal with its closure by the community); rather, you should edit the original to improve its quality. (Editing a question will "bump" it to the top of the Unanswered queue, so you get that benefit of a repost without cluttering the site with duplicates. Note, however, that non-substantive edits *just* to trigger a bump are discouraged.) Good luck!